# Absolute positioned elements are not displayed with in scrollable element

Tags: html, css

Have something seemlier like this. items has a tooltip it show on hover. but see the bellow example it hide the badge when I put the items in scroll div. basically I want to make a scroll items section and when user hover over it the badge /tooltip display absolute position.

**it also has a dropdown menu bottom of the item when hover over it.** it work without scroll div, but when I put it into scroll carousal div it not display.

[image]

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

.badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 99;
}

.scroll-x {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="scroll-x">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it also has a dropdown menu bottom of the item when hover over it. basically it is a NAV Bar with a badge and dropdown. it works fine in big screen with no scroll, I try to put scroll bar at bottom on smaller screen. and it hide badge and dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with was this:
I added static height to .list and positioned .item to the bottom

Maybe not the best answer but I hope it helps :)

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  height: 110px;   //-----
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  align-self: flex-end;  //-----
}

.badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 99;
}

.scroll-x {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="badge"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="scroll-x">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="badge"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but **it also has a dropdown menu bottom** of the item when hover over it. basically it is a NAV bar with a badge and dropdown. it works fine in big screen with no scroll, I try to put scroll bar at bottom on smaller screen. and it hide badge and dropdown.